# When to use $(selector).data() and html data-* attribute?

Tags: jquery, html

I can't classify these cases:

```
// first
$('#myDiv').attr('data-foo', 1);    

// second
$('#myDiv').data('foo', 1);
```

The first case appends `data-foo` to html tag which the id is `myDiv` and the second is not.

My question is: When to use the first and the second case?

p/s: I'm using jquery version 2.2.4

Comment: Always use `data()`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Comment: With `data` you can attach complex types if i'm not mistaken

Comment: With `.attr('data-foo')` you can attach CSS, eg. `[data-foo]:before {content: attr(data-foo);}`